# Obtaining the actual steps of a solution that has been obtained using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

If dynamic programming is used to obtain some optimum solution for a problem. How do you reconstruct the actual steps that lead to that solution?

For example, in the 0-1 knapsack problem you use the recurrence

[image]

Using this we can get the maximum value that can be present in the knapsack. How do you find the actual items present.

Can this be generalized for any dynamic programming solution. For eg. To find the actual nos that are part of the longest increasing subsequence whose solution has been obtained using dynamic programming.

Comment: Well this is a very good question, with an excellent answer by @aiobee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Can this be generalized for any dynamic programming solution.***

No, you can't *in general* find the actual solution by inspecting the final values in the DP-table.

If the algorithm simply looks for some optimum value, it will typically **discard information regarding *how*** each value was computed.

In a DP-solution the cell on row *R* could for instance depend on the maximum value in row *R-1*. Unless the algorithm records which cell was chosen, it will not be possible to reconstruct the actual solution based on the resulting table.

You should however always be able to attach additional information to each cell describing where the value comes from, for instance by **references to previously computed cells which the current cell depends upon**, and use this information to reconstruct the actual solution.

Comment: For problems like the knapsack problem the actual solution can be obtained using DP-Table. Is there some way to determine if you need to maintain the book-keeping table or not? How does one maintain the book keeping table.

Comment: You basically just need to keep track of the history that lead up to the resulting value. When dealing with *max* functions for instance, you need to record *which* value was considered max.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to store additional information that will allow you to reconstruct the choices made at each step, while filling-up the dynamic programming table. Sometimes, the table itself contains such information. For instance, in the 0/1 knapsack problem, here's how you can find out the items used to reach the optimal solution (notice that only the table is needed):

```
# 0/1 knapsack. O(nC) time, O(nC) space,
# also returns the index of the items to pick
# V: values, W: weights, C: capacity

def integral_knapsack_items(V, W, C):
    table = integral_knapsack_table(V, W, C)
    i, j, items = len(W), C, []
    while i != 0 and j != 0:
        if table[i][j] != table[i-1][j]:
            items.append(i-1)
            i, j = i-1, j-W[i-1]
        else:
            i -= 1
    return (table[-1][-1], items)

def integral_knapsack_table(V, W, C):
    m, n = len(W)+1, C+1
    table = [[0] * n for x in xrange(m)]
    for i in xrange(1, m):
        for j in xrange(1, n):
            if W[i-1] > j:
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j]
            else:
                table[i][j] = max(table[i-1][j],
                                  V[i-1] + table[i-1][j-W[i-1]])
    return table
```

In the above code, you call `integral_knapsack_items()` with `V` (an array of values), `W` (an array of corresponding weights) and `C` (the capacity of the knapsack), and the procedure returns a tuple with the maximum value obtained while filling the knapsack, and the indexes of the items used to reach that value.

Comment: I think that I downvoted it, and honestly, I don't remember. I think it had something to do with a coding competition. If you edit it, I can remove the downvote; sorry

Comment: @K.Gkinis thanks for answering after all this time :) I just edited it!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to revisit your steps in the DP. In case of 0-1 knapsack, lets say the original DP function was **solve**, and the function **reconstruct** will give you the actual solution (I'm writing the code in C++):

```
int solve(int pos, int capacity)
{
    if(pos == no_of_objects) return 0;
    if(memo[pos][capacity] != -1) return memo[pos][capacity];

    int r1 = solve(pos + 1, capacity); //dont take
    int r2 = 0;
    if(weight[pos] <= capacity)
    {
        r2 = solve(pos + 1, capacity - weight[pos]) + profit[pos]; //take
    }
    return memo[pos][capacity] = max(r1, r2);
}

void reconstruct(int pos, int capacity)
{
    if(pos == no_of_objects) return; //you have completed reconstruction

    int r1 = memo[pos + 1][capacity]; //dont take
    int r2 = 0;
    if(weight[pos] <= capacity)
        r2 = memo[pos + 1][capacity - weight[pos]] + profit[pos]; //take

    if(r1 > r2) 
    {
        reconstruct(pos + 1, capacity);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Take object " << pos << endl;
        reconstruct(pos + 1, capacity - weight[pos]) + profit[pos]; 
    }
}
```

After executing **reconstruct**, it will print all those objects that give you the optimal solution. As you can see, at most **no_of_objects** calls will be made in the **reconstruct** function.

Similarly, you can reconstruct the solution of any DP greedily.

Answer (score 0):

Most dynamic programming algorithms use Memoization and Backtracking.  Memoization is kind of a look up table where the algorithm stores state information on each step.  Once the algorithms finish, then it use backtracking to go from the last state of the algorithm to the previous one.  On knapsak this could be obtained by storing the "where I came from?" value.  How M[i,w] was calculated?  Either from m[i-1.w] or m[i-1, w-wi] + vi.  Search for Memoization and Backtracking to get more examples.

Comment: Usually memoization is used to refer to top-down solutions, and dynamic programming to refer to bottom-up solutions.